# Python -- Curl works, requests lib doesn't

Tags: python, curl, django-rest-framework, python-requests, pycurl

This works from the command line:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '<my data>' http://my_user:my_pass@my_url
```

This doesn't work from a python script:

```
 res=requests.post(
  'http://my_user:my_pass@my_url',  
  json='<my data>')
```

What happens is it hits the server, but doesn't authorize. The REST API is built with Django Rest Framework, and I get

```
{"detail":"Invalid username/password."}
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

Password includes these special characters % ( \

I escaped \ , so it's a double backslash. I also tried with r in front of string, and 4 backslashes.

I tried with `auth=('my_user','my_pass')` with the different escapes too.

I ran it through http://curl.trillworks.com/ and still that didn't work.

Tomorrow I'm going to change my password to something simple and test.

If that doesn't work, I'm giving up and adding a bash script at the end that just runs that curl command.

Comment: use auth param for passing credentials.

Comment: What are you passing as data and what usr are you using when you use `auth=...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I escaped \ , so it's a double backslash. I also tried with r in front
>   of string, and 4 backslashes.

The \ in the curl command was to escape a parenthesis. It wasn't part of the password.

I removed it and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to try setting the authentication using `requests` library like this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

Comment: `auth=('user', 'pass')` is exactly the same as importing HTTPBasicAuth and doing it yourself which the OP already tried according to their question so there should be no difference.

Comment: Yes, both worked. My problem was the backslash in the curl statement was to escape the parenthesis, and not part of the password itself.